# Redirecting to localhost/Dashboard on WordPress - XAMPP

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache

When every I click to any link of my website, it redirects to localhost/dashboard why is it happening I created new database but it didn't resolve my issue.

My XAMPP ver is 0.3.2.4

Comment: Wordpress holds the url in its database that you use on the install process. There are documents on the WordPress site that tell you how to change these

Comment: XAMPP 0.3.2.4 ?? Really?

Comment: Have you checked the `siteurl` and `home` fields in the `wp_options` table in the DB, to make sure that the correct URL is set?